# Setting Cursor Color in GTK 3 (since 3.16)

Tags: css, gtk3

In a gtk3 program, I can use CSS to set e.g. white text on black background. But the text cursor (I-beam) remains black, unusable on dark background.

Only current info that I could find among all the outdated docs [says](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.override_cursor):

> **override_cursor**(cursor, secondary_cursor)
>
> **Deprecated since version 3.16:** This function is not useful in the context of CSS-based rendering. If you wish to change the color used to render the primary and secondary cursors you should use a custom CSS style, through an application-specific Gtk.StyleProvider and a **CSS style class**.

Setting `cursor-color` with CSS doesn't work, I get

> The style property GtkWidget:cursor-color is deprecated

**How can I set cursor color in GTK 3 nowadays?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `caret-color` in your GTK CSS to change the focused cursor color in GTK apps (like Zim).

```
#zim-pageview* {
  background-color: #584624;
  color : #FFFFFF;
  caret-color: white;
}
```